# Problemas al instalar el paquete de Pystan y ejecutarlo el Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter, anaconda, anaconda3

He instalado el paquete de **Pystan** pero después de hacerlo, en teoría correctamente, al querer importarlo en Jupyter, me sale el siguiente error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[49], line 1
----> 1 import pystan

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pystan'
```

El paquete lo he instalado dentro de un nuevo entorno creado, siguiendo las siguientes instrucciones para Windows y saliéndome todo correcto: https://pystan2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/windows.html

He utilizado el código `!pip freeze` y me sale lo siguiente:

```
pystan==2.19.1.1
python-dateutil @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/python-dateutil_1626286286081/work
pytz @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/pytz_1680088766131/work
pywin32==303
pywinpty==2.0.10
pyzmq @ file:///D:/bld/pyzmq_1663830622471/work
qtconsole==5.4.3
QtPy==2.3.1
scipy @ file:///C:/bld/scipy_1637806996411/work
Send2Trash @ file:///D:/bld/send2trash_1682601429724/work
simpleconjoint==0.0.1
sip @ file:///D:/bld/sip_1665592565341/work
```

He hecho una comprobación, que no se si radica aquí el error, para comprobar si está instalado en la base de anaconda y cuando introduzco el siguiente código `is_installed_in_base('Pystan')` me devuelve `"FALSE"`

Por último, he leído que la solución podía estar en instalarlo directamente desde la hoja de Jupyter, metido dentro del entorno creado, utilizando:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install Pystan
```

y me sale el siguiente error cuando lo ejecuto:

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [11734 lines of output]
  C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-owaj2ne2\pystan_6e67db716bec4d55be8aaa4b34618374\setup.py:235: DeprecationWarning:
  
    `numpy.distutils` is deprecated since NumPy 1.23.0, as a result
    of the deprecation of `distutils` itself. It will be removed for
    Python >= 3.12. For older Python versions it will remain present.
    It is recommended to use `setuptools < 60.0` for those Python versions.
    For more details, see:
      https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/distutils_status_migration.html
```

Esto es todo lo que he utilizado hasta ahora para hacer comprobaciones y sin saber muy bien donde está el problema.

Comment: Has mencionado anaconda, si estás usando anaconda deberías instalarlo con `conda install`